# Bootstrap 3.0.3 & 3.2.0 difference

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The same code produces different result in bootstrap 3.0.3 & 3.2.0 versions

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date: </label>
        <input name="startdate" class="form-control" type="date">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Optional Search String: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="vertical-align:bottom">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

3.0.3
[image]
[3.0.3 example](http://www.bootply.com/111796#)

3.2.0
[image]
[3.2.0 example](http://www.bootply.com/rMKxnatFpp)

How can I achieve the same layout with new version of bootstrap ?

Comment: older version use width auto instead of width 100%, you could change it like this: DEMO - http://www.bootply.com/G2GAh4ZL4r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `width: auto;` instead of `width: 100%;` to `.form-inline .form-control` - **[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/G2GAh4ZL4r)**

**CSS:**

```
.form-inline .form-control {
    width: auto;
}
```

**[EDITED]**

As per your older version, that use `width:auto;` for only media `min-width:768px`: - **[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/VoETw8Jem5)**

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display:inline-block;
        width:auto;
        vertical-align:middle
    }
}
```